# vertical align image and two lines of text

Tags: html, css

I have the below code, where an image is correctly vertically aligned with a lines of text. but when i try to make it two lines, its not all vertically centered.

this is my current code for one sentence:

```
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5CEiuNs.png"/> one sentence
    </div>
```

```
<pre>
.container{
    font-size:20px;
}
.container img{
    height: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</pre>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/euvszf5o/

and this is when I try to add a second line:

```
    <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5CEiuNs.png"/>
    <span>
      one sentence
      <br/>
      second sentence
    </span>
</div>
```

```
<pre>
.container{
    font-size:20px;
}
.container img{
    height: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</pre>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9sdtqp85/

and this is how i want it to look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii2IB.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to play with fontsize a bit to fine tune it now :)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container img {
  height: 1.2em;
}

.container span {
  line-height: 0.8
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5CEiuNs.png" />
  <span>
    one sentence
    <br/>
    second sentence
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Addition to this, you can add line-height property to span. You can play around the values between 0.5 to 0.8 which suites your design

Comment: thanks this is great. i tried to play with line-height as suggested but it didnt do any difference. is there any way to close the gap between the sentences? i'd like them closer to each other.

Comment: Modified the answer take a look.

Comment: thanks, yeah i messed up. i added it on the container, not the span, now its perfect. will leave this Q open for a bit longer if i find any other issue, but will set this as accepted answer soon. thanks Karol.